# Golang closure not storing captured variables?

Tags: function, go, closures, return-value

In this block of code below, I expect the output to be 0, 1, 2, 3,..., 9. However, only the output 10, 10,...,10 is produced.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func adder() []func() {
    out := []func(){}
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        out = append(out, func() { fmt.Println(i) })
    }

    return out
}

func main() {
    out := adder()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        out[i]()
    }
}
```

My mental model suggests that a new function is generated and stored every time in the for-loop, but it doesn't seem to be the case. Is there a solution to generating new functions without modifying the signature (no parameters or global variables) but still keeping the current value of i?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A new function *is* created every iteration, but they all close over the same variable, `i`. That variable is updated with every iteration until the last, so when you go through and execute all those functions, they all refer to the same `i`, with the same value, `10`.

If you don't want that behavior, you must *not* close over the loop variable:

```
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    temp := i
    out = append(out, func() { fmt.Println(temp) })
}
```

Comment: Thank you :). Just noticed this as well based on your explanation: https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines

Comment: It's a little less self explanatory, but when the scope is _actually_ different, you can even mask `i` by simply doing `i := i`. Could lead to confusion though. Just mentioning it as a possibility that I've seen done in many places.

Comment: @Bob yes, that's the same idea, but as your issue was unrelated to goroutines I didn't want to confuse the issue. It's definitely most commonly seen as it relates to goroutines.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior has changed in the Go version 1.22, have a look at the [release note](https://go.dev/doc/go1.22#:%7E:text=Previously%2C%20the%20variables%20declared%20by%20a%20%22for%22%20loop%20were%20created%20once%20and%20updated%20by%20each%20iteration.%20In%20Go%201.22%2C%20each%20iteration%20of%20the%20loop%20creates%20new%20variables%2C%20to%20avoid%20accidental%20sharing%20bugs.), which says:

> Previously, the variables declared by a "for" loop were created once and updated by each iteration. In Go 1.22, each iteration of the loop creates new variables, to avoid accidental sharing bugs.

And this example on the playground: https://go.dev/play/p/djpXI9ZqunG